# How to use Burstable pods on Autopilot GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I don't manage to create burstable (or besteffort) pods on my Autopilot GKE cluster.

When I follow [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-bursting-gke) to create a burstable pod, and copy paste the example, it creates a Guaranteed pod. However I have to remove the `spec.nodeSelector` and `spec.tolerations` settings of the example as they are optional, and don't seem to work.

My cluster is a few days old and runs K8S 1.28.5 with the default settings. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: The behaviour of my cluster seems to be like with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258957/gke-autopilot-changes-the-limits-requests-resources-of-a-pod-in-a-wrong-way

But it supposed to support Burstable pods.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your input. Please check and let me know if you have any other issues. I am happy to assist you further.

Comment: Yes, I specify both the limits and the resources as the documentation tells me to do. I actually copy paste the example from the documentation, so I think something is going wrong somewhere. I read the documentation many many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google updated their documentation and it now requires a more recent GKE version on the "rapid" channel.

I updated my cluster and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

GKE Autopilot silently overwrites limits with the requests, there’s no visible warnings.

As said, In an Autopilot cluster, each Pod is treated as a `Guaranteed QoS Class` Pod, with limits that are equal to requests. Autopilot automatically sets resource limits equal to requests if you do not have resource limits specified. If you do specify resource limits, your limits will be overridden and set to be equal to the requests.

So, you are getting a guaranteed pod even though you have created a burstable pod. However, Autopilot adds an `autopilot.gke.io/resource-adjustment` annotation on the Deployment when a resource config is overridden. Therefore, if you set the requests and the limits are not set/requests are less than the limits, then the pods can burst into available [bursting capacity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-bursting-gke#burstable-capacity).

Please refer to the [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-resource-requests#resource-limits) for setting resource limits in autopilot.

**EDIT:**

I have reproduced the usecase that has been given in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/pod-bursting-gke). After deploying the burstable pod.yaml, I am getting the Guranteed QoS class for the burstable pod deployment  which is incorrect. For this you can create a new public issue tracker(PIT) stating that the example in the document is giving false output.[image]

In case you want to report a new issue, please do not hesitate to create a new [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) thread describing your issue. The Google Engineering team will validate the issue.

Note : The Issue Tracker is a forum for end users to report platform-wide bugs and request features to improve google cloud products.

Comment: Yep, that's what the documentation say.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: When I follow the documentation to create a burstable pod, I get a guaranteed pod instead. Autopilot modifies my resources for unknown reasons and leaves a `autopilot.gke.io/resource-adjustment` annotation. I don't see anything in the logs, and my cluster has all the requirements. I think the documentation is outdated or incomplete, but I would be glad to be proven wrong.